# How do I return more than one value from DataFrame.groupby.rolling.apply?

Tags: pandas, apply, rolling-computation

I am looking to apply a function on a rolling window. I organize the data using the `groupby` method. But the function must return two values; when I do that I get the error:

> ```
> cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
> ```

When I run `df.groupby(['A'])['B'].rolling(2).apply(function)` with a function that returns a single value it works. But then I modify the code to use a function that returns two values:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'B':[0.2,0.5,1.0,1.2,1.7,1.9,2.1,2.4]})

def basic_function(y):
    sum1=0
    sum2=0
    for x in y:
        sum1=sum1+x*x
        sum2=sum2+x*x*x
    return sum1/len(y),sum2/len(y)

df.groupby(['A'])['B'].rolling(2).apply(basic_function)
```

I was expecting the code to add two new columns to the dataframe. Instead I get an error message.